# How to suppress display of comma when rendering a number column?

Tags: list, formatting

This is for SP2010. I have a custom content type which has a column defined as a Number column type. For other business reasons, it does need to be a Number type, so switching it to "Single line of text" is not an acceptable option.

The trouble I have is, when this column is rendered in a form, a list, ect., the column is displayed using a comma for a thousands separator. My data is always a six-digit number, but is not intended to be displayed with a comma.

I see nowhere any means of supressing the display of a comma. I'm not aware of any "formatNumber()" sort of options for lists, but sure wish there was.

**Is there any means of of forcing the display of a Number column to supress those commas?**

Answer (score 1):

One way to address the comma appearing on a list view would be to add a calculated column that returns the number column's value as a single line of text, then show the calculated column in the list view.

This would not address the comma appearing on the display form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting for data views.

Apply conditional formatting to a Data View

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Apply-conditional-formatting-to-a-Data-View-3263849d-4444-4f8c-80a9-680058e1bd52?CorrelationId=5f7e0664-e1f6-4d8d-90ba-ca78915f833d&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

You could also create another column that holds the text value.

Displaying numeric fields in SharePoint 2010 without commas

http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2011/11/displaying-numeric-fields-in-sharepoint-2010-without-commas/